# Как найти индекс конкретного элемента, csv?

Tags: python, база-данных, pandas, numpy

У меня есть датабаза и в ней я должен найти сколько лет самому высокому.
Найти самого высокого я смог:

```
dif = pd.read_csv('h03.csv')
print(dif.height.max())
```

но как найти индекс именно этого элемента, что бы потом вывести то что мне нужно.

[image: датабаза]

Answer (score 0):

```
dif = pd.read_csv('h03.csv')
value = dif.height.max()

dif[dif.height == value]
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: У меня после сроки print(dif.age[dif.height == value]) выводит то что мне нужно, но и ещё Name: age, dtype: int64 почему так?